# How to handle concurrency with an asynchronous singleton bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to implement a singleton bean in Java EE, which starts a VPN connection on demand.

Thus I created a Class like:

```
@Singleton
class VPNClient{
  private boolean connected;

  @Lock(LockType.READ)
  public boolean isConnected(){
    return this.connected;
  }

  @Asynchronous
  @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
  public void connect(){
    // do connect, including a while loop for the socket:

    while(true){
      // read socket, do stuff like setting connected when VPN successfully established
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have another bean, which has the demand for the VPN connection and tries to create it:

```
  class X {
    @Inject 
    VPNClient client;

    private void sendStuffToVPN(){

      // call the async connect method
      client.connect();

      // wait for connect (or exception and stuff in original source)
      while(!client.isConnected()){

        // wait for connection to be established
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      }
    }
  }
```

My problem now is, that because of the connect method, that never ends until the connection is destroyed, the write lock it has, will block all reads to isConnected().

**[Update]**

This should hopefully illustrate the problem:

- Thread 1 (Bean X) calls Thread 2 (Singleton Bean VPNClient) .connect()
- Now there is an endless write lock on the singleton bean VPNClient. But because the method was called async. Thread 1 proceeds:
- Thread 1 (Bean x) tries to call Thread 2 (VPNClient.isConnected()), but has to wait for the release of the write lock (which started with connect()).
- Then the J2EE container throws an javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException because it waited until timeout.

Is there a good pattern to solve this kind of concurrency problem?

Comment: @JanHruby is there a pattern for that? I've not read the whole Java EE documentation, but I think it is forbidden to create new Thready by hand in Java EE

Comment: sorry, it is discouraged, that is right

Comment: why do you lock the thread if you do an async call?

Comment: @Roman My thought was, that the connect method is setting class properties, so it should be Lock(LockType.WRITE) -- the default. As the question states, I'm looking for a good pattern to solve this. For example I could use @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN) and do it myself, but that would be painfull (at least for me)

Comment: Why don't you use "the default"?

Comment: It is (default for a singleton bean), I don't have to write it, but I will update the sample source to show it.

Comment: I still don't understand why do you block reads? If you do it at least do notify other thread before going to sleep.

Comment: Maybe now I don't understand your question, but I am not blocking it, the J2EE Container is blocking it. Because the connect method is using a write lock on the singleton bean and so the container does not allow any read methods to be called. So I'm looking to find a J2EE "way of things" to push the connect method either do another thread or to do something I'm unaware of.

Comment: You need to debug this issue to show where and when threads are locked and why it was happened. Without it it's difficult to make you understood.

Comment: There is no need to debug, because it is default behavior. I updated the question and tried to show the steps that lead to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Lock(LockType.WRITE) locks all methods in the singleton bean until the called method has completed even if the caller has moved on via @Asynchronous.

This is the correct behaviour if you think about it - concurrency problems can happen from  other method calls to the bean if processing is still in progress.

The way to get around this is to set @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN) on your singleton to handle concurrency and locking of access to the connection yourself.

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html#indexterm-1449 for an introduction.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 class X {
    private void sendStuffToVPN(){
      VPNClient client = new VPNClient();

      // call the async connect method
      new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run()
                    {
                       client.connect();
                    }
      }).start();

      // wait for connect (or exception and stuff in original source)
      while(!client.isConnected()){

        // wait for connection to be established
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I updated my question sample source to show that it is an injected object. That said, I think it is forbidden in Java EE to create new Threads by hand.